# Get pixel coordinates of a element on a map in UWP

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, windows-10, uwp-maps

So I've got a map. On it I have some XAML elements positioned by geolocation. I need to find their coordinates in pixels in order to detect when they overlap each other (for grouping purposes) 
I can't seem to find a way. If I get `MyMap.MapItems` I only get the collection of objects I binded to the map.
Any ideas how to do it?

Comment: If your question is about the UWP MapControl, it has a [GetOffsetFromLocation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.maps.mapcontrol.getoffsetfromlocation.aspx) method, that *Converts a geographic location to a point on the map*. No need to do any calculation yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good question. I currently had such a problem. Here's an article that describes exactly what you need to do. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb259689.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

the code if you don't have time to read it:

```
    private const double EarthRadius = 6378137;
    private const double MinLatitude = -85.05112878;
    private const double MaxLatitude = 85.05112878;
    private const double MinLongitude = -180;
    private const double MaxLongitude = 180;

private static double Clip(double n, double minValue, double maxValue)
            {
                return Math.Min(Math.Max(n, minValue), maxValue);
            }

public static uint MapSize(int levelOfDetail)
        {
            return (uint) 256 << levelOfDetail;
        }
public static void LatLongToPixelXY(double latitude, double longitude, int levelOfDetail, out int pixelX, out int pixelY)
        {
            latitude = Clip(latitude, MinLatitude, MaxLatitude);
            longitude = Clip(longitude, MinLongitude, MaxLongitude);

            double x = (longitude + 180) / 360; 
            double sinLatitude = Math.Sin(latitude * Math.PI / 180);
            double y = 0.5 - Math.Log((1 + sinLatitude) / (1 - sinLatitude)) / (4 * Math.PI);

            uint mapSize = MapSize(levelOfDetail);
            pixelX = (int) Clip(x * mapSize + 0.5, 0, mapSize - 1);
            pixelY = (int) Clip(y * mapSize + 0.5, 0, mapSize - 1);
        }
```

Comment: Wow, a lot of math involved in this. Thank you. Let me try

Comment: That worked like a charm. For anyone interested: it gets the pixels coordinates relatively to the map not to the app frame, which is nice.

Comment: For explanation, this implements the inverse transformation of the [Mercator Projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercator_projection), which is used by all common map controls, e.g. the UWP MapControl.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use @Clemens suggestion of the [GetOffsetFromLocation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.maps.mapcontrol.getoffsetfromlocation.aspx)method?

It does all that math for you, and will still work even if the MapControl moves away from a Mercator projection.